# Cocoa-Why should I put my statusItem in ApplicationDelegate?

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa

I'm new to OSX application development and I want to make a status bar app.

To show a `NSStatusItem` in my status bar, I put my `statusBar` item in the `ViewController` at first. It did work.

```
//ApplicationDelegate.h
#import <Cocoa/Cocoa.h>

@interface AppDelegate : NSObject <NSApplicationDelegate>

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSStatusItem *statusBar;

@end
```

.

```
//ApplicationDelegate.m
#import "AppDelegate.h"

@interface AppDelegate ()

@end

@implementation AppDelegate


- (void)applicationDidFinishLaunching:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to initialize your application
}

- (void)applicationWillTerminate:(NSNotification *)aNotification {
    // Insert code here to tear down your application
}

-(void)awakeFromNib{
    self.statusBar = [[NSStatusBar systemStatusBar] statusItemWithLength:NSVariableStatusItemLength];

    self.statusBar.title = @"T";


    self.statusBar.highlightMode = YES;

}
@end
```

**(Here I'm not sure whether I should use `awakeFromNib` method when I'm using `storyboard` instead of `nib`.)**

However,when I read some demo code, I found that I should do that in the `ApplicationDelegate` class.

Why? I think that is part of my **VIEW** as I'm following the **MVC** rule.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NSStatusItem is not related with the window or any view. It can stay in the NSStatusBar even when there is no view attached.

Therefore it is a good practice to create and init NSStatusItem in ApplicationDelegate class.